# Where is _CONF_DIR being loaded from?

Tags: azerothcore

newbie question, where is _CONF_DIR being loaded from in:

```cpp
std::string const ConfigMgr::GetConfigPath()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_configLock);

#if AC_PLATFORM == AC_PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    return "configs/";
#else
    return std::string(_CONF_DIR) + "/";
#endif
}
```

assumed it was an environment variable / cmd line variable but adding -D_CONF_DIR="..." doesn't seem to be doing anything; seems to be defaulting to /usr/local/etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable was generated from cmake, which generated it from the input variable "CONF_DIR" - i.e. one of  the arguments I passed to cmake was `-DCONF_DIR="/root/azerothcore-wotlk/env/dist/etc"`.